# Há como dividir uma tabelas em várias pequenas e manter as querys?

Tags: postgresql

Estou com um problema no meu servidor, minha tabela `artigos` possui 5,5 milhões de linhas e um select normal demora cerca de 8 segundos para executar. Enão tive um brilhante ideia, irei dividir minha tabela em 10 tabelas, sendo que os artigos serão distribuidos da seguinte forma:

```
id % 10 -> tabela_destino
```

Quando meu sistema buscar meu artigo, irá buscar em uma tabela de 550 mil em vez de 5,5 milhões, e o tempo de consulta será muito menor, cerca de meio segundo. Porém o sistema que está consultando é o Django, então não tem como fazer a busca na mão ( OU pelo menos acredito que não).

Então decidi manter a tabela normal com 5,5 milhões, que possuirá apenas o id, e junto as outras 10 tabelas. O que quero saber se existe um forma de automatizar o postgres para buscar um campo em outra tabela:

Vou exemplificar:

Minha tabela inicial possui os sequintes campos:

```
Artigos:
id: integer (pk)
text: string
data: timestamp
```

Então irei dividir em outras:

```
Artigos0
id: integer (pk)
text: string
data: timestamp

Artigos1
id: integer (pk)
text: string
data: timestamp

....
```

E a tabela inicial apenas terá o id:

```
Artigos:
id: integer (pk)
```

Mas quando tiver um select do tipo `select texto from Artigos where id = 1`, quero que o postgres já saiba que tem que procurar na tabela `Artigo1` sem precisar alterar a query. Existe alguma forma de fazer isso automaticamente?

Comment: Pesquise por Table Partitioning. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html

Answer (score 1):

Nao sei se eh possivel esse tipo de automacao no postgres, mas se optar por realmente dividir as tabelas, voce pode usar **Raw Queries** do Django pra buscar direto na tabela que voce deseja (fazer a busca na mao, como voce disse).

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
id = 1
resultado = Artigos1.objects.raw("SELECT texto FROM artigos1 WHERE id=%d", id)
```

Referencia: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries